# Number of instances counter subclass

Tags: java

Eclipse keeps informing of an error when I try to implement a counter for a number of instances when called by the constructor. I've been searching on the matter, but the solutions are the exact thing eclipse won't let.
The problem is in `Student() { count++; }` in the subclass.

`Implicit super constructor Dosije() is undefined. Must explicitly invoke another constructor`

Main file

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestDosije {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String jmbg=null;

    System.out.println("ime osobe: ");
    String ime= in.next();

    System.out.println("prezime osobe: ");
    String prezime= in.next();
    System.out.println("jmbg: ");

    while(!(Dosije.jesteJMBG(jmbg =in.next()) ))  {


    }
    String ime_prezime= ime + " " + prezime;

    Dosije dosije = new Dosije(ime_prezime, jmbg);
    System.out.println(dosije.toString());

    System.out.println("broj indeksa: ");
    int index= in.nextInt();

    System.out.println("godina upisa: ");
    int upis= in.nextInt();

    System.out.println("studije: ");
    int studije= in.nextInt();

    Student student = new Student(dosije, index, upis, studije);

    System.out.println(student.toString());
    System.out.println(student.getCount());


}

}
```

The superclass

```
public class Dosije {

private String ime_prezime;
private String jmbg;

public Dosije(String ime_prezime, String jmbg) {
    this.ime_prezime=ime_prezime;
    this.jmbg=jmbg;
}

public Dosije(final Dosije d) {
    ime_prezime=d.ime_prezime;
    jmbg=d.jmbg;
}

public String getImePrezime() { return ime_prezime; }
public void setImePrezime(String ime_prezime) { this.ime_prezime= ime_prezime;}

public String getJMBG() { return jmbg; }
public void setJMBG(String jmbg) { this.jmbg= jmbg;}

public String toString() {
    return ime_prezime + "\njmbg: " + jmbg;
}

public static boolean jesteJMBG(String jmbg) {


    if(jmbg.length() != 13) {
        System.err.println("jmbg ima 13 cifara");
        return false;
    }


    for(int i=0;i < jmbg.length(); i++)  {
        if(!(Character.isDigit(jmbg.charAt(i))) ) {
            System.err.println("jmbg nije broj!");
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

}
```

The subclass of which instances I'm trying to count

```
public class Student extends Dosije{

private int br_index;
private int god_upis;
private int profil_studija;

private static int count=0;

 Student() {      
    count++;     //the devil himself
}

public Student(final Dosije d, int index, int upis, int studije){
    super(d);
    br_index=index;
    god_upis=upis;
    profil_studija=studije;

}

public Student(final Student s) {
    super(s);
    br_index=s.br_index;
    god_upis=s.god_upis;
    profil_studija=s.profil_studija;

}

public void setProfil(int n) {profil_studija=n;}

public int getCount() { return count;  }

public String Studije(int i) {
    if(i == 0)
        return "Osnovne";
    else if(i == 1)
        return "MSc";
    else
        return "PhD";

}


public String toString() { 
    return super.toString() + "\n" + "broj indeksa: " + br_index + "/" + (god_upis % 100) + "\n" 
            + "studije: " + Studije(profil_studija);
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Student()` constructor doesn't pass compilation since the super class doesn't have a parameterless constructor, so the implicit call to `super();` added by the compiler doesn't pass compilation.

You can add a `public Dosije() {}` constructor to prevent that compilation error.

However, you might want to increment `count` in the other `Student` constructors too, in order to count the total number of instances created, regardless of which constructor was used.

Comment: Excuse me for potentially sounding newbish, but where is my parameterless constructor in the superclass?  Both constructor have parameters.

Comment: @monolith937 That's the point. You are missing a parameterless constructor in the superclass, which is the reason the parameterless constructor in Student class doesn't pass compilation.

Comment: @monolith937 In your Student class you have a parameterless-constructor: `public Student(){ count++ }`. Since it's a child class, the compiler automatically tries to compile it into this: `public Student(){ super(); count++; }`. But, since your Dosije-class doesn't have a parameter-less constructor, you get the error displayed.

Comment: @monolith937 I mistakenly wrote "does have" instead of "doesn't have". fixed now :)

Comment: Oh, that clarifies things. Thanks, it works and it shed some light on my understanding of inheritance :)